# How to fix 'Cannot implicitly convert type' error in C#?

Tags: c#

I am doing the flare-on challenge (Memecat Battlestation) and I've decided to.. Well bypass it, the Demo Shareware one got bypassed, but corrupted flag so I thought I'd try the full version, I tried the full version but I've gotten an error

This is for the 1st Flare-On challenge named Memecat Battlestation, I am running Windows 7 64-bit, the error is in VictoryForm.cs

```
    private static IEnumerable<byte> AssignFelineDesignation(byte[] cat, IEnumerable<byte> data)
    {
        byte[] s = BattleCatManagerInstance.InvertCosmicConstants(cat);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        return data.Select(delegate (byte b)
        {
            i = (i + 1 & 255);
            j = (j + (int)s[i] & 255);
            BattleCatManagerInstance.CatFact(s, i, j);
            return b ^ s[(int)(s[i] + s[j] & byte.MaxValue)];
        });
    }
```

I've expected it to just build without any errors but I've gotten this error:

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>`'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line:

```
return b ^ s[(int)(s[i] + s[j] & byte.MaxValue)]
```

... returns an `int`, because that's the type of the `^` operator you're using. You can just cast the result to `byte`:

```
return (byte) (b ^ s[(int)(s[i] + s[j] & byte.MaxValue)]);
```

I'd personally use a lambda expression rather than an anonymous method though:

```
return data.Select(b =>
{
    i = (i + 1 & 255);
    j = (j + (int)s[i] & 255);
    BattleCatManagerInstance.CatFact(s, i, j);
    return (byte) (b ^ s[(int)(s[i] + s[j] & byte.MaxValue)]);
});
```

Comment: you mean "the statement returns an **int**" right? Or am i missing something?

Comment: @ilkerkaran: Doh! That's absolutely what I meant. Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: I'll flag this as the best answer once the 6 minutes is over, this actually helped me. Thanks, I just have to find a way to fix 'Resource identifier 'MemeCatBattlestation.VictoryForm.resources' has already been used in this assembly' now.